# How to convert (accumulated) $\rm Wh$ to Watt/seconds?

Tags: energy, dimensional-analysis, power, unit-conversion

I can measure **Wh**, but I need to do a graph with **Watt/second**. How can I achieve that?

Comment: How sure are you that you need W/s? That's quite an obscure unit usually.

Comment: I need to transform Watthour to watt/sec in order to represent it to a graph and know the exact Watt per second. Why obscure?

Comment: Because Watt is already energy per time, so you would be graphing the *change of energy per time*. If you did that e.g. for a house, you would see peaks whenever you turn electronic devices on or off. It's a legit unit, just not that commonly used, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the rate of change of Wh (with respect to hours) to find the amount of Watts as a function of time.  Then, you need to find the rate of change of Watts (with respect to seconds) to find the W/s as a function of time.

In essence, you need to differentiate it twice, which is finding the slope of the slope of the graph.

Comment: Is it the same if instead of **Wh**, I have **consumed Joules** and I want to calculate **Joules/seconds** and represent them in a graph?

Comment: @just_learning Yes, indeed.

Comment: How can I do this process with python? What should I look for? I mean, obviously I cannot differentiate (2 times) on numbers. I need to transform the data (or graph) into an equation first.. Am I right?

Comment: If I apply least mean squares and find the approximate equation of the accumulated **Wh** can I differentiate 2 times that equation and get the **Watt/second** ?

Comment: If I have this column with accumulated **Wh** : 400, 420, 460, 500... And I want to find **y** (Watt/hour), and I say: **y1** = 420-400 = 20, **y2** = 460-420 = 40, **y3** =500-460 = 40 etc... Does this concept work? Sorry for too many questions...I am trying to implement it, because 2nd level derivatives with Least Mean Squares do not help...

Comment: Your comments further support my suspicion that you really want to calculate Watt=Joules/second, and not Watt/second = Joules/second/second.

Comment: @noah: Ok, same thing... suppose I have **accumulated Joules** and I need to calculate **Joules/sec** does what I describe above work?

Comment: It's not the same, otherwise there would be no need to clarify. The above answer calculates W/s as you asked, not J/s.

Comment: Ok, please see the whole picture, I need to transform an **accumulated value** into **value/second**...